# How to find the included angle between the given known sides

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Question:
In a triangle $ABC$, $AB = a-b$ & $BC = 2\sqrt{ab}$ , find $\angle B$ ??

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know anything about $AC$ from here?

Answer (score 1):

Clue:

In this triangle ABC.If you consider conventional naming styles of sides.
The length Side AC = b units , AB = c units , BC = a units.

Now we know that $a = 2\sqrt{ab}$ $\Rightarrow a^2 = 4ab$.
We will get two values of a from this viz. $a = 0  $ & $a = 4b$.We cannot use a = 0 as triangle cannot exist .Use a = 4b.Find c in terms of b and substitute below.

Now use cosine rule:

$$cosB = \frac{a^2+c^2-b^2}{2ac}$$